# Writing into the existing directory Dataframe using partitionBy

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In the below code ,I am not able to write the dataframe into an existing directory,It just exits from the spark submit job.Is there a way I can write it to existing directory other than creating a new directory?

Here test is a dataframe

`test.repartition(100).write.partitionBy("date").parquet(hdfslocation)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always write to the existing directory, if the filenames are different in each write. You should find a mechanism to change names of the output files.

If you want to `Overwrite` existing files in existing directory, then you don't need to change the filenames but simply use `mode` option as

```
test.repartition(100).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).partitionBy("date").parquet(hdfslocation)
```

There are other mode options you can play with : `Append, ErrorIfExists, Ignore, valueOf, values`